# Filter table by last digit in cell value

Tags: excel

Just as the title states. I need to filter or sort a table based on the last digit in a column cell. I've looked into advanced filters, but can't seem to get any to do what I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a helper column like below and sort of filter accordingly,

[image]

Column B formula:

```
=RIGHT(A2)
```

Filtered table:

[image]

Sorted list:

[image]

Comment: Cool, this will work great. Simple solution too. Thanks!